# Replace and range replace output

Tags: tcl

I am trying to replace a line in a file by memory and my case as below;

1. First case; Why below script in each run still add blank line after last list string? any options without memory?

   ```
   set lines [split [read $fp] "\n"]
   close $fp
   lset lines 5 {TESTT}
   set fp [open $flnm w]
   puts $fp [join $lines \n]
   close $fp
   ```
2. Second case; how to replace by range lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data starts with a newline at the end; because `split` is using it as a *separator*, that results in an empty element at the end of the list it produces.
Then, when you write it out, `join` recreates the contents of the file (subject to the alterations you added) and `puts` adds a newline afterwards because `puts` is documented to do that.

You probably want to use the `-nonewline` option because you're taking control of the newlines yourself:

```
puts -nonewline $fp [join $lines \n]
```

---

To replace a range of elements of a list (and hence a range of lines), you should use the `lreplace` command. However, that takes a list value and returns a list value; it doesn't do an in-place edit like `lset` does:

```
set insertion [list "insert me #1" "insert me #2" "insert me #3" "insert me #4"]
set lines [lreplace $lines 5 7 {*}$insertion]
```

Comment: @Andre, you could also use `read -nonewline` instead of `puts -nonewline` -- that takes care of the issue when you fetch the data, so your list of lines already does not have an empty last element.